# PHP send an appointment to Lotus Notes, dolar char in headers

Tags: php, lotus-notes, appointment

I'm trying to send an appointment to Lotus Notes, I am able to send something but not all headers are consider in my mail. At first I found that it is not allowed to use '*' in header name so I found that if I will use '-' instead of '*' the server will send the email with the '_' at the end. This I had to use in case when I want to set header '_ViewIcon'. 
Now I have another problem. Some Lotus headers start with dolar, like '$Abstract' ... But when I set this header using PHPMailer I will get on the Lotus side instead of $Abstract the $24Abstract.
So I can to do if these chars are not allowed for RFC 822 ? How can I send a correct appointment to Lotus Notes.

With PHP Mailer I'm using these headers:

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader("\$PublicAccess: 1");
$mail->AddCustomHeader("-ViewIcon: 148");
```

But in the Lotus when I open detail of email I can see:
$24PublicAccess.

**Solution:**

I find out the solution which is helpful for me. The special characters like $,_,-,... are not allowed only for header name. So I send from Lotus Notes appointment to my GMail and then I open the source of mail from GMail. I found many Lotus headers with this format:

```
X-Lotus-Item: 1; name=$PublicAccess; type=300
// and type=300 means number I think
```

So when I rewrite all my headers into this format, it's working now!
I can setup all headers which contains $ or any other special character.

Comment: Your code exists outside of the Lotus Notes environment, so as far as the Lotus software is concerned your message is not coming from a trusted source. I don't think it should allow you to set the $PublicAccess field, because that would allow anyone in in the world the ability to put a publicly visible appointment on a Lotus Notes user's calendar.

Comment: I found a way, see my solution chapter. But still it is a strange. Maybe it is a weekness of Lotus Notes.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that private reserved items can be sent that way. There is some risk of an outsider sending a calendar appointment and making it visible to the public without the recipient knowing about it. I think it might be possible to configure servers to block receiving private items in order to avoid that risk, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

try with simple quote and without a backslash

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader('$PublicAccess: 1');
```

Comment: This will lead to Undefined variable because server will try to find a PHP variable $Public Access. Ok and if I will try it with single quotes 'text' the result is the same. $24 on the Lotus side.